# Why is the file object empty inside formik's values object on file upload form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to upload a file using formik but the file object is always empty and I cannot quite figure it out. Here is a link to the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-file-input-with-validation-forked-r5jqg?file=/src/App.js

I got this implementation from this issue filed on github - https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/926.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were setting an `object` which was `e.target.files[0]` to a `file` which was initially `undefined`. you need to set `e.taregt.files[0]` to       `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`. not to your state object `file` too. you need to set name and size as that is what you need for validation schema and display. I've commented the supported formats from validation schema as for `input type=file` you can directly mention the accepted formats by `accept` key.

Here is my working modified [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-file-input-with-validation-forked-vopy3?file=/src/components/CustomImageInput.js:1138-1185).

Comment: I notice that when I `alert` the formik `values` object, the file object is empty but upon console logging it, I do see the file object. My problem is that when I post the formik `values` object to the server, it shows up as an empty object inside `req.body`.

Comment: Did you checked my sandbox link ? it's working fine there.

Comment: I've updated my demo. now the file object is coming. Can you check is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Okay, as far as I can tell, the reason why the file was not properly getting posted to the server is that the payload was not of type `FormData`. To fix this, I added this - `const formData = new FormData(); formData.append("photo", values.file);`, in Formik's `onSubmit` handler and then passed `formData` as the payload to `axios`.
Initially I thought, the file object being empty on `alert` was causing the issue but that is not the case.